# Time analysis of an algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, time

I am stuck on figuring out the running time of an algorithm.

```
import gas

def detect_collisions(balls):
""" 
Detect any pairs of balls that are colliding.
Returns a set of ball_pairs.
"""

set_of_collisions = set()

for i in range(len(balls)):
    b1 = balls[i]
    for j in range(i):
        b2 = balls[j]
        if gas.colliding(b1, b2):
            set_of_collisions.add(gas.ball_pair(b1, b2))

return set_of_collisions
```

balls is a list of ball objects.  and the gas.colliding() function calls a distance function which both run in constant time.  I am getting n for the outer for loop (where n is the length of the balls list) and I am getting n^2 for the inner for loop because it has to run n! times I believe.  Since everything else is a constant running time, this gives a time of n * n^2 or n^3.  Did I go about this the right way?

Comment: Can you just surround the algorithm (or a call to the algorithm function) with calls to a time function?  `time_t start_time = time();...CallAlgorithm();... time_t end_time = time();.  time_t duration = end_time - start_time;`.  Or, you can use calls to `clock();` for better resolution.

Comment: @ryyker I should have mentioned that I was looking for O() notation, not actual time for the algorithm.  Luckily wookie919 knew what I meant and helped. But, your method is something I have used in the past when I need exact time.

Comment: No problem,  By the way, if you wanted to accept wookie's answer, there is a hollow check mark.  It should be visible to the left of his answer.  ( I see that you are new, and may not know about that yet )

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering how to give him credit and I overlooked the giant check mark somehow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner `for` loop does not run `n!` times, and even if it did,`n!` is not equivalent to `n^2`.

Just work through it:

- when `i = 1`, `j` iterates from 0 to 0
- when `i = 2`, `j` iterates from 0 to 1
- when `i = 3`, `j` iterates from 0 to 2
- when `i = 4`, `j` iterates from 0 to 3
- when `i = n`, `j` iterates from 0 to `n - 1`

`1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + n = n(n+1)/2`

Thus your algorithm runs in `O(n^2)` time.

Comment: +1 This is likely what OP is looking for.  I am curious though, how you would extend this notation to _figuring out the running time_, i.e. in terms of msec of running time?  (Never really used big O notation)

Comment: @ryyker, that would be completely dependant on the hardware.

Comment: @wookie919 thank you so much. I got n! mixed up and that definitely led to some of my confusion. You cleared it up very well

Comment: @wookie919 just did! Thankfully ryyker told me how!